# NoSuchMethod exception with Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, windowbuilder

I am trying to call a swing panel from a jar using reflection
this is the code

```
public class coolUI extends JPanel{

public coolUI{

   //swing code here ( made by windowbuilder )

 }
}
```

Here is the code that i use to call it from

```
String className = "plugins.plugin1.coolUI";
Class UI = cl.loadClass(className);         
Method theUI = UI.getMethod("coolUI");
Object a = UI.newInstance();
theUI.invoke(a, null);
```

What i am trying to do here is to load a jar, and to attach the UI inside the jar into a tabbedpane, though i can do this without reflection, i have no idea on how to do this with it.

Comment: Not valid Java.

Comment: This comment is not helpful, at all, at least you could tell me how should i make it valid.

Comment: I am saying the code you are trying to invoke with reflection is not valid Java. This question makes no sense.

Comment: Well then how/why does it work if it isn't valid java?

Comment: As far as what you have posted here; it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are doing this dynamically, am I right?
If so in you should use .getConstructor() instead of getMethod().

Like this:

```
cons = class.getConstructor();
```

Answer (score 0):

`coolUI.coolUI()` is a constructor and therefore `Class.getMethod("coolUI")` throws a `NoSuchMethodException`.

To make it a method a return type must be added

```
public void coolUI() {
    //swing code here ( made by windowbuilder )
}
```

Comment: if I add a return type the UI becomes blank (it doesn't display stuff that i put in with windowbuilder, also viewed from windowbuilder itself it's blank too).

Comment: Well, it seems, that this fixed the `NoSuchMethodException`. Can you somehow determine whether the method is actually called? - e.g. putting in a debug statement - If so, your current error is most likely unrelated to this question.

Comment: Yes, the method is indeed called. "If so, your current error is most likely unrelated to this question." what should i do now? can't post anymore questions, should i give free rep/delete or thats breaking the rules?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not too familiar with this. However, you can always look at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) or at meta, for example [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).